# list all possible solutions for the system of equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, systems-of-equations

i am doing multivariable calculus and asked to find the max and min that the function can attain, and basically the first step you do is to find the partial derivatives and set them equal zero  then i ended up with the following system of equations:

$$0 = 2xe^{-x^2-y^2}(2 - 2x^2 - 3y^2)$$
$$0 = 2ye^{-x^2-y^2}(3 - 2x^2 - 3y^2)$$

here is my attempt to solve it:
$if$ $x=0$ then  $2x^2+3y^2=2$ which means if $x=0$ then $y=±\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ but that isnt the right answer.

please walk me in step by step on how you solve it

Comment: If x is zero, then you have satisfied the top equation, I would then work on satisfying the second equation given x is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that when $x=0$, the first equation is satisfied. Therefore, the second equation will be satisfied when $3-3y^2=0$ or when $2y=0$. This gives $y=\pm 1$ or $y=0$ (Note that $e$ to any power is never zero).

Similarly, if $y=0$, then the second equation is easily satisfied and the first equation is zero only if $x=0$ or $2-2x^2=0$, which means $x=\pm 1$ or $x=0$.

The only other case is to consider when both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero. In such a scenario, you have to simultaneously solve $2-2x^2-3y^2=0$ and $3-2x^2-3y^2=0$.

Setting these equations equal to one another gives $2=3$, which is obviously not true. Thus, there are no solutions outside of the ones listed in the first two paragraphs of this answer.

In total, the solutions to the set of equations are $(x,y) = (0,0), (\pm1,0),(0,\pm1)$.

I hope this clarifies things for you.